# My android Application instance(Application class) is destroyed after I stay my application in background after 2-3 minutes

Tags: java, android

I use `Application` class to store my android application global parameters.But when I go to other app and stay my app to background for about several minutes, my app can not run again. Because I get parameters from the `Application` class but now it becomes empty.

My question is why it like that and how to solve this problem?
 And I also saw a thread follows:

[Returning after a period of inactivity in my Android Application causes destroy set Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091292/returning-after-a-period-of-inactivity-in-my-android-application-causes-destroy)

The answer is using `onSaveInstanceState()`. But how can I save all my application parameters in it? 
 Thank you

.

Comment: i guess you didn't see all the recommended "look-at-these-before-you-post" questions.
look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use shared preferences to save your data? OS kills your application if it is on background and it needs resources...